# Safari - Content not displaying until user scrolls or page size changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have two html tables with variable numbers of columns. I'm using js to create "frozen" columns by cloning the column to be frozen into a new division and hiding it in the original division.

The original division is made scrollable with max-width and overflow.

For most browsers, this functions without any issue. Except Safari.

In Safari, the scrollable div for the top table, and only the top table, isn't being rendered after the JS completes in certain circumstances.

The content is in the inspector with all changes applied from my js function, but appears as a blank space until the user either waits 30 seconds and scrolls, or interacts with any page element that changes the size of the body.

This behavior only happens if no scrollbar would appear in the scrollable div.

Has anyone seen similar behavior with Safari before and what resolved it?

Edit: I haven't been able to reproduce this outside of the full environment, but a copy of the basic code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nknapp/q0xhgtzp/25/

HTML

```
<div id="divContentSum" class="col-12">
   <div id="ctSumLeftTableSpan" class="name-table" >
   </div>
   <div id="ctSumMain" class="values-table">
      <div id="tableDiv-ctSum">
         <table style="" summary="True" class="table-cell" id="ctSum">
            <colgroup>
               <col id="colLbl">
               <col id="colValueSum">
               <col id="colTot">
            </colgroup>
            <thead style="display:table-header-group">
               <tr class="cb-table-header h48">
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="colBlank"><span>Type</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-0" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col1</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-1" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col2</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-2" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col3</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-3" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col4</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-4" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col5</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-5" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col6</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-6" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col7</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="colhName"><span>Totals</span></th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr row="1">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row1" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Number</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol0_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol1_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum1-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol2_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum2-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol3_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum3-TH colhName"><span>5</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol4_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum4-TH colhName"><span>29</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol5_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum5-TH colhName"><span>1</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol6_Row1" class="" headers="colValueSum6-TH colhName"><span>6</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row1" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>128</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr row="2">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row2" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Average</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol0_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum-TH colhName"><span>2.4</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol1_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum1-TH colhName"><span>4.4</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol2_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum2-TH colhName"><span>3.9</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol3_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum3-TH colhName"><span>2.2</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol4_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum4-TH colhName"><span>3.1</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol5_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum5-TH colhName"><span>5.0</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol6_Row2" class="" headers="colValueSum6-TH colhName"><span>3.3</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row2" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>3.3</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr row="3">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row3" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Percent</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol0_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum-TH colhName"><span>43%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol1_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum1-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol2_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum2-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol3_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum3-TH colhName"><span>40%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol4_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum4-TH colhName"><span>76%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol5_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum5-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueSum_CtCol6_Row3" class="" headers="colValueSum6-TH colhName"><span>67%</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row3" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>76%</span></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="ctSumRightTableSpan" class="totals-table-det" >
   </div>
   </div>
<div id="divContentDet" class="col-12">
   <div id="ctDetLeftTableSpan" class="name-table-det" >
   </div>
   <div id="ctDetMain" class="values-table-det">
      <div id="tableDiv-ctDet">
         <table style="" Detmary="True" class="table-cell" id="ctDet">
            <colgroup>
               <col id="colLbl">
               <col id="colValueDet">
               <col id="colTot">
            </colgroup>
            <thead style="display:table-header-group">
               <tr class="cb-table-header h48">
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="colBlank"><span>Type</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-0" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col1</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-1" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col2</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-2" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col3</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-3" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col4</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-4" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col5</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-5" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col6</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-6" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col7</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-7" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col8</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-8" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col9</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-9" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col10</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="ctSpanner-10" colspan="1" ><span class="font-table-heavy font-white">Col11</span></th>
                  <th scope="col" class="tbl-head" id="colhName"><span>Totals</span></th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr row="1">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row1" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Number</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol0_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol1_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet1-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol2_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet2-TH colhName"><span>14</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol3_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet3-TH colhName"><span>5</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol4_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet4-TH colhName"><span>29</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol5_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet5-TH colhName"><span>1</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol6_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet6-TH colhName"><span>6</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol7_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet7-TH colhName"><span>10</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol8_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet8-TH colhName"><span>21</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol9_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet9-TH colhName"><span>13</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol10_Row1" class="" headers="colValueDet10-TH colhName"><span>1</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row1" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>128</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr row="2">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row2" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Average</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol0_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet-TH colhName"><span>2.4</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol1_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet1-TH colhName"><span>4.4</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol2_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet2-TH colhName"><span>3.9</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol3_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet3-TH colhName"><span>2.2</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol4_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet4-TH colhName"><span>3.1</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol5_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet5-TH colhName"><span>5.0</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol6_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet6-TH colhName"><span>3.3</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol7_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet7-TH colhName"><span>3.8</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol8_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet8-TH colhName"><span>3.0</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol9_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet9-TH colhName"><span>3.5</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol10_Row2" class="" headers="colValueDet10-TH colhName"><span>4.0</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row2" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>3.3</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr row="3">
                  <td id="colLbl_Row3" headers="colLbl-TH colBlank" class=""><span>Percent</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol0_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet-TH colhName"><span>43%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol1_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet1-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol2_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet2-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol3_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet3-TH colhName"><span>40%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol4_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet4-TH colhName"><span>76%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol5_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet5-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol6_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet6-TH colhName"><span>67%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol7_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet7-TH colhName"><span>80%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol8_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet8-TH colhName"><span>76%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol9_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet9-TH colhName"><span>69%</span></td>
                  <td id="colValueDet_CtCol10_Row3" class="" headers="colValueDet10-TH colhName"><span>100%</span></td>
                  <td id="colTot_Row3" headers="colTot-TH" class=""><span>76%</span></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="ctDetRightTableSpan" class="totals-table-det" >
   </div>
   </div>
```

JS(jQuery 3.3.1)

```
function stripFirstColumns(source,num) {   
    //clear any existing tables
    $('#'+source+'LeftTableSpan').children().remove();
    //construct left table
    var $Tbl = $('<table id="'+source+'LeftTable">');
    $Tbl.addClass( $('#'+source).attr('class'));
    //copy header to get attributes and delete children
    var $tHead = $('#'+source+' thead').clone().off().appendTo($Tbl);
    $tHead.find('tr').remove();
    //copy body without attributes or children
    var $tBody = $Tbl.append(document.getElementById(source).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].cloneNode());
    //count rows needed
    var hRows = $('#'+source+' thead tr').not('.noLoop');
    var bRows = $('#'+source+' tbody tr').not('.noLoop');

    //clone header content
    for(i= hRows.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //clone header rows and remove inner content, negative counting to preserve order
        var $tRow = $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+')').clone(false).prependTo($tHead);
        $tRow.find('th').remove();
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            //clone header cells and then remove cell from source, negative counting to preserve order
            var $tCell = $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+') th:eq('+j+')').clone(true,true).appendTo($tRow);
            $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+') th:eq('+j+')').hide();
            }
        }

    //clone body content
    for(i= bRows.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //clone body rows and remove inner content, negative counting to preserve order
        var $tRow = $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+')').clone(false).prependTo($tBody);
        $tRow.find('td').remove();
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            //clone body cells and remove cell from source, negative counting to preserve order
            var $tCell = $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+') td:eq('+j+')').clone(true,true).appendTo($tRow);
            $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+') td:eq('+j+')').hide();
            }
        }
    //insert table into the left span
    $('#'+source+'LeftTableSpan').html($Tbl);
}

function stripLastColumns(source,num) {       
    //console.log('run right for '+source);

    //clear any existing tables
    $('#'+source+'RightTableSpan').children().remove();
    var ignore = 'noLoop';
    //construct right table
    var $Tbl = $('<table id="'+source+'RightTable">');
    $Tbl.addClass( $('#'+source).attr('class'));
    //copy header to get attributes and delete children
    var $tHead = $('#'+source+' thead').clone().off().appendTo($Tbl);
    $tHead.find('tr').remove();
    //copy body to get attributes and delete children
    var $tBody = $Tbl.append(document.getElementById(source).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].cloneNode());

    var hRows = $('#'+source+' thead tr').not('.noLoop');
    var bRows = $('#'+source+' tbody tr').not('.noLoop');

    var index = $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq(0) td').length - 1;

    //console.log('head '+hRows.length+' body '+bRows.length+' index '+index);

    //clone header
    for(i= hRows.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var $tRow = $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+')').clone(false).prependTo($tHead);
        $tRow.find('th').remove();
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            var target = index - j;
            var $tCell = $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+') th:eq('+target+')').clone(true,true).prependTo($tRow);
            $('#'+source+' thead tr:eq('+i+') th:eq('+target+')').hide();
            }
        }

    //clone body
    for(i= bRows.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //console.log('clone body '+i);
        var $tRow = $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+')').clone(false).prependTo($tBody);
        $tRow.find('td').remove();
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            var target = index - j;
            //console.log('clone cell '+target);
            var $tCell = $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+') td:eq('+target+')').clone(true,true).prependTo($tRow);
            $('#'+source+' tbody tr:eq('+i+') td:eq('+target+')').hide();
            }
        }

    $('#'+source+'RightTableSpan').html($Tbl);
}

function fixHeights(source) {
    //get number of rows
    var rows = $('#'+source+' tr').length;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        //get heights from each row

        var h1 = $('#'+source+'LeftTable tr:eq('+i+')').height();
        var h2 = $('#'+source+' tr:eq('+i+')').height();
        var h3 = $('#'+source+'RightTable tr:eq('+i+')').height();

        //calculate max height
        var hMax = Math.max(h1,h2,h3);

        //console.log('row '+i+' - '+h1+','+h2+','+h3+' - Max = '+hMax);

        //set the cells within the row to the max height
        $('#'+source+'LeftTable tr:eq('+i+')').children().height(hMax);
        $('#'+source+' tr:eq('+i+')').children().height(hMax)
        $('#'+source+'RightTable tr:eq('+i+')').children().height(hMax)
        }

    $('#'+source+'Main').width($('#'+source+'Main').width()+1);
}

function makeScroll(source,left,right) {
    //source is the ID of the source table, left and right are the number of columns on those sides to freeze
    stripFirstColumns(source,left);
    stripLastColumns(source,right);
    fixHeights(source);
    document.getElementById(source+'LeftTableSpan').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    document.getElementById(source+'Main').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    document.getElementById(source+'RightTableSpan').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
}

makeScroll('ctSum',1,1);
makeScroll('ctDet',1,1);
```

CSS

```
.name-table {
    float:left;
    max-width:130px;
    }

.values-table {
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    max-width:300px;
    }

.totals-table{
    float:left;
    max-width:80px;
    }

.name-table-det {
    float:left;
    max-width:120px;
    }

.values-table-det {
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    max-width:300px;
    }

.totals-table-det{
    float:left;
    max-width:80px;
    }

.z-0 {
    z-index: 0;
    }

th[id^=ctSpan] {
    background: #505050!important;
    background-color: #505050!important;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    font-size: .9rem;
}

#ctSum th, #nameTable th, #totalTable th {
  background: #505050!important;
    background-color: #505050!important;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    font-size: .9rem;
}
.col-12 {  
width:100%;
display:block;
height:130px;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I've added an example of the code, but haven't been able to reproduce the issue without everything.